# How to prevent a password or other sensitive information from being stored in the bash history when using grep?

Tags: bash, security, passwords, grep

I had to grep recently for a password that may have been saved in a file. I did not want that line to show up in the bash history.

How can I prevent a password or other sensitive information from being stored in the bash history when using grep? For example, how can I get grep to read the pattern from stdin or console?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If you put `HISTCONTROL=ignorespace` in your .bashrc, and you put a space before the command name, it will not be added to your history.

```
$ export HISTCONTROL=ignorespace
$ grep "passwd" secret_password_file.txt   # added to history
$  grep "passwd" secret_password_file.txt  # not added to history
```

Comment: FWIW: The question in the title and the question in the body are completely different. I answered the question in the title.

Comment: Your criticism is appropriate. I just edited the title. Is it better now? I still think (and so it seems does the community) that your answer is the most relevant.

Comment: I made an edit to your question to clarify things, making both questions (preventing something from being stored in the history and reading from stdin with grep) available. This way, all answers are still valid, but the very different solutions won't be confusing.

Answer (score 6):

Just for completeness, I answer the question in the body: how to get grep to read patterns from stdin:

You can use the `-f` option:

```
grep -f- /path/to/file
```

That will read any number of patterns from `stdin`, one per line. (`-` means `stdin`; you could also specify a file with patterns, one per line.) `grep` will match lines in `/path/to/file` which match any of the specified patterns.

Comment: Thanks for that. That is a good contribution and a handy trick to use elsewhere as well, say when an or'ed pattern is needed

Answer (score 2):

This is the best I could come up with:

```
grep $(read -p "Pattern: "; echo $REPLY) .*
```

Is this safe enough? Is there anyway to recover the pattern other than scrolling the terminal? Is there a nicer way?

Comment: You can use `read -s` to prevent echo (see also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1923435/how-do-i-echo-stars-when-reading-password-with-read)). The secret will be visible in `ps` output though. You can use instead `grep -f /dev/stdin *` (or `grep -f - *`) so that grep will read the pattern(s) from a file instead, end input with `^D`, or: `(read -es; echo $REPLY) | grep -f - *`

Comment: The capture shell should have double quotation marks around it. At the moment, this will break if the user enters spaces or some special characters.